# Error: @angular/platform->browser/platform-browser"' has no exported member 'DOCUMENT'

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

> '"E:/Projects/eLearning/angular/Quill/quill/node_modules/@angular/platform->browser/platform-browser"' has no exported member 'DOCUMENT'.  22 import { >DOCUMENT } from '@angular/platform-browser';"

[image: screenshot of error]

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please add a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and add some more information please.

Answer (score 4):

If you use DOCUMENT from @angular/platform-browser, you should start to import this from @angular/common since Angular 6